# Vuetify 3 Data Table current-items?

Tags: vuetifyjs3

In Vuetify 2, there was an @current-items event that fired anytime the data changed or got sorted. It allowed me to track the currently displayed list in memory.

In Vuetify 3, there doesn't seem to be a similar event. The items can be sorted by clicking on the header, but is there some way to get the newly sorted list?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is now `@update:options="myMethod($event)"`

Answer (score 0):

@current-items in vuetify 2 returned the sorted and filtered items
visible on the screen. (Or as the original post put it: track the currently diplayed list)

This was AWESOME because it was the SORTED view and was only the current pages items.

@update:options returns a .sortBy object and some pagination info which tells you how you would have to resort the filtered items...not the same thing and not nearly as useful.

vuetify3 v-data-table should in my opinion do the same thing or at least expose the sorted version of the items so they can be used without having to use custom sort and reinvent the wheel.

USE CASE: I want to be able to select the items only on the currently displayed page. Without @current-items I will have to override all filtering and sorting functionality of v-data-table in order to determine the current page items using the pagination and sort object returned in @update:options

vuetify2 correctly solved this by providing @current-items event on v-data-table.

Answer (score 0):

I use a workaround (not fancy at all) for getting VDataTable internal data:

```
<v-data-table>
    <template #bottom="data">
        <slot name="bottom" :any_name="internalData = data" />
    </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Where internalData is reactive field of your component. When slot of v-data-table is updated (#bottom in example), internal data is assigned to current component's variable inside calculation of fake property ('any_name' in example)

Slot <template #**bottom**="data"> can be any slot that provides necessary data (**body, body.append, body.prepend, bottom, colgroup, default, tbody, tfoot, thead, top**)

Currently this allows to get access to such data: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#slots-body

In your case (**@current-items**), prop '**items**' contains items that currently displayed on page in sorted order.

Comment: Perhaps this PR could be merged after suggestions from the authors that exposes events for getting filtered data or sortered data:
https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/pull/19382